# The instance of entity type 'Decks' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{CardId: 578}' is already being tracked

Tags: mysql, asp.net, entity-framework, api, asp.net-core

im new to EF-Core and trying around. I´m stuck on a Problem where i want to Update or Insert Entries in a MySQL Table.

The Model looks like this:

```
    public partial class Decks
    {
        public int DecklistId { get; set; }
        public int CardId { get; set; }
        public int Amount { get; set; }
        public bool Maindeck { get; set; }
        public virtual Cards Card { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The Entity Configuration is the following:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Decks>(entity =>
                {
                    entity.HasKey(e => new { e.DecklistId, e.CardId, e.Maindeck })
                        .HasName("PRIMARY"); ;

                    entity.HasIndex(e => e.CardId);

                    entity.ToTable("decks");

                    entity.Property(e => e.DecklistId).HasColumnName("decklistID");

                    entity.Property(e => e.CardId).HasColumnName("cardID");

                    entity.Property(e => e.Maindeck).HasColumnName("maindeck");

                    entity.Property(e => e.Amount).HasColumnName("amount");

                    entity.HasOne(e => e.Card)
                        .WithOne()
                        .HasPrincipalKey<Decks>(b => b.CardId);
                });
```

Atleast in my Repo im using this Code to find out if the Data should be updated or inserted.

```
public async Task<StandardResponse> UpdateDeck(List<Decks> deckCards)
        {
            StandardResponse errors = new StandardResponse { message = null, status = 200 };
            try
            {
                deckCards.ForEach(x =>
               {
                   Decks existingCard = _context.Decks.Find(x.DecklistId,x.CardId, x.Maindeck);
                   if (existingCard == null)
                   {
                       _context.Decks.Add(x); <---- Here occurs the Error
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       _context.Entry(existingCard).CurrentValues.SetValues(x);
                   }
                   _context.SaveChanges();
               });
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException ex)
            {
                return new StandardResponse { message = ex, status = 501 };
            }
            return new StandardResponse { message = "Deck updated!", status = 200 };
        }
```

The Problem appears, when i have to Object that have the same DecklistId and the same CardId. Even if the Maindeck property is different i get the error and i cant explain myself why...
Here is an List of Objects i want to Insert/Update.

The first Object will be added. The Second Object is of course not found on the database and at the Add-Statement the error occurs.

```
[ 
{ 
    "decklistId": 28,
    "cardId": 578,
    "amount": 4,
    "maindeck": true
},
{
    "decklistId": 28,
    "cardId": 578,
    "amount": 4,
    "maindeck": false
}
]
```

What could it be?

Thanks for helping guys!

Comment: The first and second objects are exactly the same? What are you expecting here?

Comment: What is your version of asp.net core?When i use asp.net core 2.2 and use your code.It could work well to add and update.Did you do any other operation before requesting `UpdateDeck` method?

Comment: @Rena I am using asp.net core 3.1 and i think i figured it out. The main problem was, that i used my dbContext before to get the "existingCard" and that caused a very weird error. When i use a second context for the add method : `using var _context2 = new MTGContext();` then it works as expected.

Comment: @ChrisPratt sorry i corrected it. Of course the objects differ in the maindeck attribute.

Comment: That's not a solution. It "works" because the new context doesn't have the previous entity attached, because of course, it's a new context. However, you should never new up a context yourself (it should always be injected), and using two context instances will cause inconsistencies when you call SaveChanges and such.